# How is this done to work in production, Django

Tags: python, django, http

I have a Django rest API. The API consumes Google Vision Api.
When I try a call with a local file on localhost, it works just perfectly.

However, when I do the same in production on a live server, the file is not found.

Basically, what am doing is getting a local file path to do the vision API query like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/search/image?q=/Users/user/Documents/graphics/images/testlogo.png
```

That works fine.

But if I try the same thing when the site is live in production

```
http://vesm.com/api/search/image?q=/Users/user/Documents/graphics/images/testlogo.png
```

I get a file not found exception. So my question is, how do I do a get request with a locally stored image?

I am trying to create an image search API.
What I have been doing is when someone picks a file, I get the local file path, as vision API just requires the file path.

Any guide here will be helpful.

Comment: You need to set up nginx to serve static files.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: @basckerwil my app is on google  cloudrun, how do I go about that?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/serving-static-files

Comment: you probably didn't understand my question. My static files for my site work just fine. But searching an image on vision Api doesn't work in production because the search query file is stored locally on my computer.